# how to store in a variable in its script format as string using php

Tags: php

I want to store this script below as a variable using a text area form but when I do and echo the variable, the browser interprets the code. I don't want this, I just want to store the script "as is" in a variable so I can use that variable for further manipulation. any ideas how I can accomplish this using a text area form in php?

```
<a href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B008EYEYBA" rel="nofollow noreferrer"><img border="0" src="http://ws.assoc-amazon.com/widgets/q?_encoding=UTF8&ASIN=B008EYEYBA&Format=_SL110_&ID=AsinImage&MarketPlace=US&ServiceVersion=20070822&WS=1&tag=mytwitterpage-20" ></a><img src="http://www.assoc-amazon.com/e/ir?t=mytwitterpage-20&l=as2&o=1&a=B008EYEYBA" width="1" height="1" border="0" alt="" style="border:none !important; margin:0px !important;" />
```

btw, below is the exact php variable that I want when the user put the script above in a text area.

```
$str = "<a href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B008EYEYBA" rel="nofollow noreferrer"><img border="0" src="http://ws.assoc-amazon.com/widgets/q?_encoding=UTF8&ASIN=B008EYEYBA&Format=_SL110_&ID=AsinImage&MarketPlace=US&ServiceVersion=20070822&WS=1&tag=mytwitterpage-20" ></a><img src="http://www.assoc-amazon.com/e/ir?t=mytwitterpage-20&l=as2&o=1&a=B008EYEYBA" width="1" height="1" border="0" alt="" style="border:none !important; margin:0px !important;" />";
```

any help is greatly appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use like this

```
<?php
$str = '<a href="http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008EYEYBA"><img border="0" src="http://ws.assoc-amazon.com/widgets/q?_encoding=UTF8&ASIN=B008EYEYBA&Format=_SL110_&ID=AsinImage&MarketPlace=US&ServiceVersion=20070822&WS=1&tag=mytwitterpage-20" ></a><img src="http://www.assoc-amazon.com/e/ir?t=mytwitterpage-20&l=as2&o=1&a=B008EYEYBA" width="1" height="1" border="0" alt="" style="border:none !important; margin:0px !important;" />' ;
echo htmlentities($str);
?>
```

Comment: @anagnam that's nice I have also changed your $str variable which was wrap in double quot to single quot

Comment: There's no reason to lose your html formatting. You should use `$str= <<< END`, place your formatted html on the next line and place `END;` at the beginning of the line following your html.

Comment: @Codeguy007 : yes using heredoc is a good way but his code itself had a syntax error in it.

Comment: You mean double quotes in double quotes? What I suggested fixed that too. It's doesn't use quotes to terminate the string so don't have to escape every quote. I didn't bother mentioning htmlentitles() because it was already answered.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to output your value in HTML, you need to replace your `<` and `>` with `&lt;` and `&gt;`. Best is to use `htmlspecialchars()` function for that.

Also you were told correctly that your string has unescaped quotes in it (replace inside quotes with `\"`).